# How to disable mouse button navigation

Tags: visual-studio-code

So I just installed Visual Studio Code, and there's one issue that I'm having which is putting me off using it at all. Whenever I press my mouse buttons (Mouse Button 4) it changes the current code tab I'm in. Because I use this button as my push to talk key for TeamSpeak, it makes it an issue when I want to code. Is there a way to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: No. VS Code at this time does not offer the ability to modify keybindings for [mouse clicks](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3130)

Comment: Thinking out loud though, you might check the binding for switching editors or editor groups (unsure which one it would be) and un-assigning/disabling it. That might prevent it from doing anything.